# How define left interval for censored regression model

Tags: r

I have a censored database and I want to regress with censReg in the censReg package,  but I can't define left interval for it (I have left censored observations).

My database looks like this:

```
 ID   |   student  | year of education | familysize | age |  gender 
------+------------+-------------------+------------+-----+----------
1001  |    true    |        7          |     4      | 20  |     1
1002  |    false   |       12          |     5      | 25  |     2     
1003  |    true    |       10          |     3      | 26  |     1 
1004  |    ....
```

I have this regression:

```
censresult <- censReg (eduyears ~ familysize + gender + age + birthorder,
          left=0, right=Inf, data=childrenchar)
```

I want to say that if someone is student (it means that student is true) then it is censored observation.

[Edit] i want to regress some characteristic of people on education years of them but my database contain children who have not finished their education and not taking this into account would give biased result.it means that some children are still student when we got their information . I say that these children are censored observations and I use a censored regression model,whereby the education of a child is a latent variable which is completely observed for part of the observations, but incompletely observed for the other part of the observations.

Answer (score 0):

If this `censReg` (or "sensreg"??) function uses the 'Surv' function in package 'survival' (as do many R regression functions for censored data), then the LHS of the formula would be formed as:

```
 # wrong: censReg( Surv( eduyears, student) ~ # rest of  RHS covariates, ....
```

But that was a guess, since you did not included the name of the package from which `censReg` comes.

So I looked up "censReg" and only one package, with the same name, has a function with that name. And it doesn't appear to use that mechanism. The censoring information is provided to the "left" parameter, so it would be set to 0 because your `eduyears` variable is all positive. This function seems to accept only a single value for "left". `censReg does not appear to support variable durations for its non-censored observations. I would call this a "truncated" rather than a "censored" distribution. So I do not think "student" can be a censoring flag with that particular function. It could be used as a censoring indicator in other R regression functions (in other packages.)

I would have said you had left-truncated (at 0) and right-censored observations if the question centers around accounting for potentially incomplete duration of education. If the "characteristic" you are considering for the dependent varialbe is a yes/no (1/0) sort of variable, then a survival model might be possible. You are still not describing the research question in sufficient detail to support specific suggestions. You should perhaps be seeking local statistical advice. StackOverflow is designed to assistance with coding for problems have have a well-defined analysis approach. CrossValidated.com is for more general statistics and analysis design questions.

Comment: yes, censReg package has a censReg function.ok what is your advice to me ? I have a database that somebody in it dont finish their studies so when I want to regress I should use censored regression or tobit model for  unbiased regression. which package can help me ?

Comment: You should describe the data and the question to be answered. If it's not a truncated data situation, then I know that there are methods in the survival package (as I said.) But I need coherent problem description.

Comment: i want to regress some charectristic of people on education years of them but my database contain children who have not finished their education and not taking this into account would give biased result.it means that some children are still student when we got their information . I say that these children are censored observations and I use a censored regression model,whereby the education of a child is a latent variable which is completely observed for part of the observations, but incompletely observed for the other part of the observations.

Comment: now I want to know how should I write this code in R? I need something like if condition for determine left and right . data contains annual census of 20000 urban household and 20000 rural households.